# Complete Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the following metrics

$d_1(x, y) = |e^x - e^y|,\,\forall{x, y} \in \mathbb{R};$

$d_2(x, y) = |\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y)|,\,\forall{x, y} \in \mathbb{R}$

Are the metric spaces $(\mathbb{R}, d_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, d_2)$ complete?

I need to prove that all sequences converge to the metric spaces in order to prove that they are complete. Am I right? I'm not sure how to work with a completely arbitrary sequence in order to prove that it holds for all sequences. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be much more precise with your language: The statement

> I need to prove that all sequences converge to the metric spaces in order to prove that they are complete.

unfortunately doesn't make any sense. Completeness is the property that any *Cauchy* sequence in the space converges to a limit *in* the space. So I'd suggest that you start with a Cauchy sequence and a putative limit, and hope that your sequence converges to the limit and that the limit is in the space.

For example: Take the sequence $-1, -2, -3, ...$. Do you see why it's Cauchy with respect to the metric $d_1$? Do you see that it is divergent the space $(\mathbb{R}, d_1)$?

A similar method can be used to study $d_2$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that an arbitrary Cauchy sequence conveges or not.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in both cases, the answer is "no, it's not complete."